# JavaScript operator similar to SQL “like”

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have this function with jquery, but I need it to work like operator "like" 
Help me. 
Thank you very much for your help

works correctly if I look the whole word 
example

```
var vsearch = "home"  
var array = _.filter(objeto, function(product){ 
return product.filtro ==vsearch;

var vsearch=`H`
var array = _.filter(objeto, function(product){ 
return product.filtro ==vsearch;
```

No looks for containing the `H`

Thanks.

Comment: in the filter can't you use the various string functions like `indexOf`?

Comment: Yeah, you can do `return product.filtro.indexOf(vsearch) > -1;` inside the filter to only get products that contain vsearch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `indexOf`, which returns -1 if a string is not found, to see if the product contains the letter you're searching for.

```
var vsearch=`H`;
var array = _.filter(objeto, function(product){ 
   return product.filtro.indexOf(vsearch) > -1;
}
```

Comment: additionally if you want it to be case insensitive you can do `.toLowerCase()` to both strings.

Comment: thank you very much 
worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var stringToSearch = "The full string to search goes here";
var searchTermContains = stringToSearch.search("H");
```

This will return a -1 if no match is found.